# Every nonempty subset of $\mathbb{Z}$ that is bounded above has a largest element. (Munkres "Topology 2nd Edition" Exercise 9(a) section 4)

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, order-theory

I am reading "Topology 2nd Edition" by James R. Munkres.
The following exercise is the exercise 9(a) in section 4.

> Show that every nonempty subset of $\mathbb{Z}$ that is bounded above has a largest element.

I solved this exercise, but I am not sure my solution is right.

My solution is here:

> Let $\emptyset\neq A\subset\mathbb{Z}$ and suppose that $A$ is bounded above.
> Then, $\sup A$ exists by the least upper bound propery of $\mathbb{R}$.
> Let $c:=\sup A$.
> Assume that $A$ doesn't have a largest element.
> Since $c-1$ is not an upper bound of $A$, there is $a\in A$ such that $c-1<a$.
> Since $A$ doesn't have a largest element, there exists $b\in A$ such that $a<b$.
> Since $a<b<a+1$ doesn't hold, $a+1\leq b$.
> So, $c<a+1\leq b$.
> So, $c<b$.
> Since $c$ is an upper bound of $A$ and $b\in A$, this is a contradiction.

Comment: Why is $b < a + 1$ not true?

Comment: @AniruddhaDeshmukh Given an integer $n$, there is no integer $a$ such that $n<a<n+1$.

Comment: Is it because $b$ is an integer?

Comment: Your solution is correct but using the real numbers to prove something about the integers seems like overkill to me. If I were you I'd try to prove it without the reals.

Comment: @PedroAmaral Thank you very much.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3737392/897135 Here is a proof without using $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: @grover Thank you very much for the link.